# What am I doing wrong with this key binding?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Menu{

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image1.png");
  Action escapePressed;
  
  public Menu() {
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setIconImage(icon);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.setTitle("Nine Games");
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.add(new StartScreen());

    escapePressed = new EscapePressed();

    frame.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'), "escapePressed");
    frame.getActionMap().put("escapePressed", escapePressed);
  }

  public class EscapePressed extends AbstractAction {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Escape Pressed");
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why, but this program says that `getInputMap` and `getActionMap` don't exist. Which is weird. I could have sworn I put it all in correctly . I followed a tutorial even but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I know what i need to do when i get an answer. im not that dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems:

1. a JFrame doesn't have an InputMap and ActionMap. Only components that extend from JComponent can use Key Bindings. So to handle an exit KeyStroke you probably want to use the `JRootPane` to add your bindings
2. you don't want to use the default `WHEN_FOCUSED` InputMap because the root pane won't have focus as some other component you add to the frame will have focus. Instead you want to use the `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` InputMap.

So your code might be like:

```
//frame.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'), "escapePressed");
//frame.getActionMap().put("escapePressed", escapePressed);    
frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'), "escapePressed");
frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("escapePressed", escapePressed);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Also check out [Using Top Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for more information about the root pane.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to use `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke` as there is a level of ambiguity in how the key stroke might be triggered, this is a personal thing, but I've wasted too much time trying to debug issues related to it.

Instead, I prefer to use `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0)` instead. This is much easier to (for me) to understand and I can configure "pressed" or "released" functionality through it as well.

The default behaviour of `getInputMap()` is to generate events `WHEN_FOCUSED`, this is the same as you would expect from `KeyListener`, but you're adding your key binding to the `JFrame`, which is unlikely to ever gain focus (it's a composite component, so it doesn't make sense for it to do so).

Instead, you should try something like...

```
frame.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "escapePressed");
frame.getActionMap().put("escapePressed", escapePressed);
```

Now, personally, I think this kind of thing is probably better maintained via a component, which gets added to the frame, but this is me.